# Como alguém pode me ajudar a limitar esse elemento como está limitando no footer? Ele está sobrepondo a header quando aparece e não consigo limitar!

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #banner {
    position: fixed;        
    left: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 110px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #000;
  }
  #footer { height: 600px; background: #888; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function checarScroll() {
        var margem = 10;
        var posicao = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
        var footertop = $('#footer').offset().top;            
        var meiodapagina = window.innerHeight / 2;            
        var maximo = footertop + meiodapagina - margem;

        if (posicao < maximo) {
            $('#banner').css('bottom', meiodapagina + 'px');
        } else {                
            $('#banner').css('bottom', (margem + (posicao - footertop)) + 'px');
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(checarScroll);
    $(document).scroll(checarScroll);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:1200px">
    Conteúdo da página                
</div>
<div id="banner">
    <div class="bannerconteudo">BANNER</div>        
</div>
<div id="footer">Aqui está o footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas cade o `header` no seu código? Na sua pergunta não da para ver onde ou como vc está usando o seu `header`... Acho que nem precisa de JS ou jQuery para isso, com CSS e position:sticky vc resolve!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fala Ana, bem vinda ao Stack Overflow em Português!

Mexi um pouco no seu código e ficou assim, coloca pra rodar aqui e da uma olhadinha pra ver se atende:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

        <style>
          #cabecalho {
            background-color: #b5e61d;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 7px;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
            text-align: center;
          }
          #banner {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 110px; height: 300px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            border: 5px solid #000;
          }
          #footer { 
            padding: 10px; 
            background: #b5e61d; 
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
          }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
          var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
          var footer_top = $('#footer').offset().top;
          var banner_heigth = $('#banner').height();
          var set = scroll_top + "px";
          if ((scroll_top + banner_heigth) >= footer_top) { 
            set = (footer_top - banner_heigth*1.3) + "px";
          } 

          jQuery('#banner').animate({
              top:set
            },
            {
              duration:1000,
              queue:false
            });
        });
      });
    </script>

      </head>
      <body>

        <nav id="cabecalho"> HEADER </nav>
        <div style="height:1200px">
          Conteúdo da página                
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
          <div class="bannerconteudo">BANNER</div>        
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> FOOTER </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Sua pergunta teve a negativação de algum usuário por já tem um tópico parecido por aqui. Pra evitar negativação nas suas questões, tenta da uma procurada mais a fundo que você acha, ta bom?

Se tiver interesse de aprender melhor como funcionar e as regras da casa, visite esse [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs).

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada! É exatamente isso que queria, mas não encontrei em outro lugar. Só estou com um pouco de dificuldades de fazer isso no meu site. Vou continuar tentando... Obrigada de verdade, Octávio!

Comment: Octávio, você faz trabalhos freelancer? Como faço para entrar em contato com você?

Comment: @AnaMariaAlvesdaSilva fico super feliz em ter te ajudado. Se quiser entrar em contato, pode me chamar no [meu Twitter](https://twitter.com/lageoctavio) que conversamos melhor e passo até meu telefone.
Ainda sou estudante e não sei se consigo te atender com um serviço desses, mas podemos conversar, no mínimo posso te indicar alguém ;)